# Exponential equation: $x\times 10^{\frac{1}{x}}+\frac1x \times 10^x=20$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can somebody help me solve this equation?

$x\times 10^{\frac{1}{x}}+\frac1x \times 10^x=20$

What I did: I think the left side is decreasing I tried to show that the first derivative

$10^{\frac1x} - \frac{1}{x^2} 10^x - \frac{1}{x}(10^{\frac1x} - 10^x) \log(10)$
is negative, but I don't know how. How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  By inspection, $x=1 $ works

Comment: Well, obviously $x = 1$ is a solution.  Need to show it is the only one.

Answer (score 4):

If $x$ is negative, the left hand side is negative, so no solution.

If $x$ is positive, we can apply AM-GM twice:

$$x\cdot 10^{\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{10^x}{x} \geq 2\sqrt{10^{x+\frac{1}{x}}}\geq 2\sqrt{10^2}=20.$$

The latter inequality is an equality if and only if $x=\tfrac1x$, i.e. iff $x=1$. In this case the former inequality is also an equality, so we get

$$x\cdot 10^{\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{10^x}{x} =20,$$
if and only if $x=1$.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate that equality occurs if and only if $x =1$?  I mean, never a good idea to claim a unique solution without proving it, and I see nothing in the way of a proof, other than a claim.

Comment: "Equality occurs if "  ... But you fail to prove "only if", hence cannot claim "uniqueness" in the solution.  I agree that, from your work, $x=1$ is *a* solution.  But you haven't demonstrated that $x=1$ is *the unique solution*.  Maybe a nitpick, but, hey, this is math.se.

Comment: @amWhy Maybe my command over the English language is not good. Is the 'only if' part: $x=1 \implies $ the equation or is it: the equation implies $x=1$ ?

Comment: @Arthur, If you read the proof carefully, I also used $x+\frac{1}{x} \geq 2$. So we also need $x+\frac{1}{x}=2$ to attain the equality.

Comment: @amWhy, I request you to read the proof one more time. In order to prove that $LHS \ge RHS$ when $x$ is positive, there is an intermediary step $2\sqrt{10^{\frac{1}{x}+x}}\geq 2\sqrt{10^2}$. I'm not sure what's not clear about it.

Comment: @Arthur and amWhy, I think you guys confuse $10^{\frac{1}{x}}$ with $\frac{1}{10^x}$ and you missed the intermediary usage of AM-GM in the proof.

Comment: @amWhy, what exactly do I fail to *demonstrate* ?

Comment: @amWhy, I edited one more time. I honestly don't know how to explain it more clearly and completely than this. Can you please check again?

Comment: Okay, @Atticus.  I really am not trying to be difficult.  So I'll say no more.  I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @amWhy, please do say more. All I'm asking from you is to pinpoint a specific step like 'It's not clear how the equality case of AM-GM implies $x=1$'. Or, 'I'm not sure how $x\cdot 10^{\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{10^x}{x}\geq 2\sqrt{10^{x+\frac{1}{x}}}$'

Comment: @Atticus Very nice solution! +1

Comment: @AmWhy It is implicitly used that equality holds in AM-GM if and only if all terms are equal. In this case $x=\tfrac1x$ for the latter inequality and $x10^{\tfrac1x}=\tfrac1x10^x$ for the former.

Comment: @Atticus I have edited your answer rather liberally in order to clarify that you do indeed prove uniqueness. Feel free to revert or otherwise change my edit to your preference.

Comment: @Servaes, It's ok, thanks. I think me and amWhy have pretty much clarified it in the end :)